# Using hidden value instead of $_GET or $_REQUEST

Tags: php, get, request, hidden

I have been using hidden values for forms.

Example:

```
 <form method="post" action="page.php">
 <input type="text" name="name""
 <input type="hidden" name="book_id" value="$bookid">
 <input type="button">
 </form>
```

`$bookid` is the `$_GET` value for `book.php?id=34324`

So instead of doing `page.php?id=$bookid` I am using `$bookid` in hidden field.

My Question:  Is it harmful if i use hidden values vs using `$GET` or `$POST` in the form action?

Comment: Hidden values are perfectly fine for propagating data from one form to another. You may also consider storing the data in the user's session.

Comment: @Digital there is no point in propagating data from one form to another.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Sure there is, we've used it from time to time.

Comment: Of course, if you use the GET method, your hidden value will be very visible in the address bar, hence not hidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question: no it is not harmful to use hidden inputs in this way.

To fix the supplied code you need to give your hidden input a name and change the method to `GET`:

```
 <?php
 if(array_key_exists('id', $_GET)) {
     $bookid = (int) $_GET['id'];
 }
 ?>

 <form method="get" action="page.php">
     <input type="text" name="name">
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $bookid; ?>">
     <input type="button">
 </form>
```

Comment: It is important to sanitise any user input though, as this example does by converting $_GET['id'] to an integer. A more general alternative is htmlspecialchars():

`<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']); ?>">`

Answer (score 3):

> Question is: is it harmful if i use hidden values vs using $GET or $POST in the form action?

The answer is: actually you will have your hidden value **either in the $_GET or $_POST array** according to the chosen method. 
And no, there is no harm in using hidden inputs. Though there is no gains either.